# How to fill area under step curve using pyplot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have plotted two step curves using `pyplot.step()`, and I would like to shade in the area beneath these curves (ideally with transparent shading). `pyplot.fill_between()` assumes linear interpolation, whereas I want to see step interpolation, as displayed below:[image: step curves without shading]

How can I shade in the region beneath these curves? Transparent coloring would be great, as this would make clear where these curves overlap.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the alpha value of the fill_between to make it semi-transparent.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,50,35)
y = np.random.exponential(1, len(x))
y2 = np.random.exponential(1, len(x))

plt.fill_between(x,y, step="pre", alpha=0.4)
plt.fill_between(x,y2, step="pre", alpha=0.4)

plt.plot(x,y, drawstyle="steps")
plt.plot(x,y2, drawstyle="steps")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Why do you think people downvoted this question? Is it just because the answer is probably in matplotlib's documentation? (I imagine it is, but it isn't easy to find)

Comment: No, people downvoted because you have not shown any attempt to find the solution yourself, nor is the problem statement actually clear. (See [ask]). I was able to help here without a good problem statement because I did an experienced guess on what the actual problem is. Other people reading the question would probably not understand it or would need to put a lot of effort into finding that out by playing around with `fill_beetween` themselves.

Comment: I think you were able to understand the problem because I wrote, "How can I shade in the region beneath these curves?". This is about as clear as a problem statement as I can possibly write. I suppose I could have written "How can I shade in the region beneath these curves using pyplot?"

Comment: Oh no, this is a task, not a problem. Take "How can I plot a line in pyplot?" - this is a task you can easily google and find a solution. What makes "How can I shade in the region beneath these curves using pyplot?" different from that? Well, we don't know, until you tell us. The problem only appears at the point where you try to implement it, using `fill_between` and then observe that not the complete area is shaded. A problem description would hence include the code that uses this (best with a picture of the undesired outcome).

Comment: So I asked this question not because I was clueless on how to solve my problem, but because I figured that it might take me multiple hours of experimentation and reading documentation to figure out what you demonstrated in a few lines of code. I wasn't looking for someone to help me solve the problem, but for someone who already knew the answer; so I didn't deem it necessary to include my failed efforts. Do you think this an inappropriate use of stackoverflow? Is there a better place I can go to ask these sorts of questions?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, There is a small mistake in your answer. Look at right most column of pixels in your plot. It isn't filled with color. Do you know ho to fix that?

Comment: @dereks You would need to append `0` to your data.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest This didn't change anything `plt.fill_between(np.append(x, [0]), np.append(y, [0]), step="pre", alpha=0.3)`

Comment: @dereks I guess you mean `plt.fill_between(np.append(x, [50]), np.append(y, [0]))`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you for your answer. I placed `plt.fill_between(np.append(x, [50]), np.append(y, [0]), step="pre", alpha=0.4)` in your example above and it also didn't change anything.

Comment: @dereks Did you also do that for the `plot` or not`?

Comment: No, my plot shouldn't go to 0 at the end. I need only fill color, without drawing a line to 0.

Comment: @dereks I don't think I understand the problem in that case. I would suggest to ask a new question then with a clear problem description.

Comment: I thought it is easy to fix that's why I asked here. For now I don't want to spend much time for the sake of one pixel column. Next time I will read more about it, thank you.