# How to fill between line and function in the matplotlib 3D?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a line and a function and I need to color between  they. How can I do it?

Comment: Your question has no code, no data, no attempt. Yet I would try to help and give hints given you are a new contributor. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417496/matplotlib-fill-between-multiple-lines), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104547/how-to-fill-area-under-step-curve-using-pyplot) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) are some links which will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`plt.fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) and specify an upper and a lower bound, e.g.:

```
x = np.arange(100)

plt.figure()
plt.fill_between(x, 2*x, np.sin(x))
plt.show()
```

[image]