# Specify values on x axis for a mathplotlib.pyplot histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Given a certain dataset, I would like to create three histograms in one plot. The data (just a small snippet of a huge dataset, which would break the mold) looks like this:

```
x,         y1,        y2,      y3
2.0466115, 0,        0,        0
2.349824,  0,        0,        0
2.697959,  0,        0,        0
3.097671,  0.195374, 0.191008, 0.167979
3.5566025, 0.522926, 0.511492, 0.426324
4.083526,  0.691916, 0.6774083,0.5790586666666666
4.688515,  0.8181206,0.801901, 0.6795873333333334
5.3831355, 0.8489766,0.833376, 0.707486
6.1806665, 0.809022, 0.795524, 0.6750806666666667
```

All my x values are the same, `y1`, `y2` and `y3` represent the three different y values. I'm creating a seperate list for each column and pass them as an argument for `pyplot.hist`. You can see my code here:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
from excel_to_csv import coordinates

y1 = coordinates(1) #another method, which creates the list out of the column
y2 = coordinates(2)
y3 = coordinates(3)

bins = np.linspace(0, 10, 150)

pyplot.hist(y1, bins, alpha=0.5, label='y1')
pyplot.hist(y2, bins, alpha=0.5, label='y2')
pyplot.hist(y3, bins, alpha=0.5, label='y3')
pyplot.legend(loc='upper right')
pyplot.show()
```

This code results in the following plot (regarding the actual dataset):
[image: plot]
As far as I researched, you creating `bins` for the range of the x axis. But instead of doing so, I would like to put there my x values.

My goal is the histogram looking like this, but as a histogram (once again - regarding the huge dataset):
[image]

Comment: So you don't want bins at all? Wouldn't that be a bar plot (or scatter plot)?

Comment: I would like to represent the data as a histogram, I guess, I need bins?

Comment: Well, while what you want to achieve may be called a histogram, this is not what you would achieve via `plt.hist`. Use `plt.plot(x,y1, marker="o")` instead.

Comment: Do you simply want to fill the area under the curve? Like here: [How to fill area under step curve using pyplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104547/how-to-fill-area-under-step-curve-using-pyplot)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.histogram` and then plot the values of the histogram:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate sample data
y1 = np.random.normal(3,1,10000)
y2 = np.random.normal(5,1,10000)
y3 = np.random.normal(7,1,10000)

bins = np.linspace(0, 10, 150)

x = np.linspace(0,10000,149)

# Plot regular histograms
plt.figure()
plt.hist(y1, bins, alpha=0.5, label='y1')
plt.hist(y2, bins, alpha=0.5, label='y2')
plt.hist(y3, bins, alpha=0.5, label='y3')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.xlabel('Bins')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram plot]

```
# Compute histogram data
h1 = np.histogram(y1, bins)
h2 = np.histogram(y2, bins)
h3 = np.histogram(y3, bins)

# Compute bin average
bin_avg = bins[0:-1] + bins[1] - bins[0]

# Plot histogram data as a line with markers
plt.figure()
plt.plot(bin_avg, h1[0], alpha=0.5, label='y1', marker='o')
plt.plot(bin_avg, h2[0], alpha=0.5, label='y2', marker='o')
plt.plot(bin_avg, h3[0], alpha=0.5, label='y3', marker='o')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.xlabel('Bins')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image: Line plot with markers]

It wouldn't make sense to plot the binned data versus x because once the data has been transformed by the histogram the relationship it had with x is no longer the same.